# How to build turtlebot_simulator source files downloaded from Github?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source files for turlebot_simulator are downloaded from github using link present on ros/wiki

Please tell me how to build these source file .....
I am a bit new so please tell in detail.
Thanking you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66386/how-to-build-turtlebot_simulator-source-files-downloaded-from-github?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tutorial part where they explain you how to install Turtlebot Simulator :
ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Installing%20TurtleBot%20Simulator

You have to replace 'electric' by the name of your ROS version.

Note that as far as I know, turtlebot simulator is not stable (not working ?) on **groovy** and so there is no debs available for this version. So I wouldn't recommend you to try to install it from source.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-02**:
Hi Lucile, I am almost new to all this. Please tell me how to simulate it from source.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-03**:
If you want to use the simulator, you should better use a previous ROS version. Like fuerte and to follow the instructions which are on this link : http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Installing%20TurtleBot%20Simulator

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-03**:
yeah, I understand that is the only option at this stage.